# UITabBarController inside UINavigationController works on iOS 8 but not 7

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In iOS 7 for a view controller in a `UITabBarController` in a `UINavigationController`, the navigation bar covers up content.
In iOS 8 this is not the case, and items which have constraints in relation to the Top Layout Guide are perfectly positioned.

If I embed each tab's view controller in a `UINavigationController`, then everything looks good in iOS 7, but in iOS 8 there's a white gap between the navigation bar and the content of the view controllers.

I understand that Apple explicitly forbids this in their documentation. A `UITabBarController` should not be pushed onto a `UINavigationController`'s stack. But this is the effect that I want to achieve:

Start app at a login screen (this will be root of a `UINavigationController`). There is no tab bar yet. If login is successful, push a new `UITabBarController` onto the stack. At this point, the logged in user can switch between different parts of the app by switching tabs.

Is there a workaround? Or is there a different way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find a satisfactory way to go about it. I ended up restructuring the app so that the `UITabBarController` was the root and the Login view controller was presented modally initially.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue recently, I came up with 2 approaches. I'll use **Swift 3.0** for clarity. Hope this saves someone out there some time.

**Assumptions**
Your app starts with a `UINavigationController` which embeds your *LoginController*

**Approach 1: Using the app window (recommended)**
In your *LoginController*, when the user logs in, simply change the `rootViewController` property of your app's `keyWindow` to your desired `UITabBarController`

```
// LoginController: onLogin
let homeTBC = UITabBarController()
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = homeTBC
```

**Approach 2: Using the UINavigationController's stack**
In your *LoginController*, when the user logs in, make your desired `UITabBarController` the root view controller of your `navigationController`.

```
// LoginController: onLogin
let homeTBC = UITabBarController()
self.navigationController?.viewControllers = [homeTBC]
```

The caveat with this method is that the viewControllers in your *homeTBC* can not directly access the `navigationBar`, they would have to go through their mother-tabBarController, for example, to change the title in one of the viewControllers in your *homeTBC*, you'd have to do this:

```
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "My VC Title"
```